# Create Asp.net Server Control with canvas object of HTML5

Tags: asp.net, html, html5-canvas

I need to create control in wich i can display image and display different section of image and click on perticular area of image it will display particular image like Image map control.i need to use this control in HTML page and it will get data from server....

i am new in developing server control.

i want to use canvas object of html5 if any one can help me ...